# Loading events using a function in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using [ExtJS 3.4](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/) and fullcalendar@5.10.2 ( using jsdelivr CDN ).

My `config` Object :

```
var config = {
        events : eventsLoader, 
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        height : 500,
        nowIndicator : true ,
        editable: false,
        locale : "fr",
        showNonCurrentDates: false,
        headerToolbar: {
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay list',
            center: 'title',
            left: 'today prev,next'
        },
        footerToolbar: {
            right: "prevYear,nextYear"
        },
        buttonText : {
              today:    "Aujourd'hui",
              month:    'Mois',
              week:     'Semaine',
              day:      'Jour',
              list:     'Liste'
            }
    }
```

The `eventsLoader` function :

```
var eventsLoader =  function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({              
                url : gpao.OF.url,
                method : "POST",
                params : {
                    action : 'getEvents',
                    idCentreDeCharge : id,
                },                  
                success : function(result,response) {   
                    var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                    var jsonRes = jsonData.results;
                    var events = jsonRes.map(function(eventEl) {
                                        return {
                                            title : eventEl.title,
                                            start : eventEl.start,
                                            end : eventEl.end
                                        }
                                    })
                    console.log("events : ",events);
                    successCallback(events);
                },
                failure : function() {
                    console.error('there was an error with the Ajax request to '+gpao.CentreCharge.url);
                    failureCallback("failed");
                }
            });
      }
```

The `fetchInfo` object :

```
var now = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setYear(now.getFullYear() - 3);
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setYear(now.getFullYear() + 3);

var fetchInfo = {
        start : startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
        end : endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    }
console.log("fetchInfo : ",fetchInfo);
```

Example of the `events` array passed to `successCallback(events)` looks like this :

[image: events array]

I used a dummy events array just to test, and my calendar renders with no errors.

#### The Problem :

I'm rendering the calendar on a Tab Panel, this time using a [function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) instead of a dummy array, the first time a user selects it the calendar looks all messed up ( week days all clummed up in the top left corner on top of each other ), untill i either resize the page `CTRL` + `MouseWheel`, switch views, or click any button like `prev,next,prevYear,nextYear,today`, i'm stuck on this, any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you showing and hiding the calendar? You probably need to call the render() method when you re-display it, otherwise it can be messed up by being in a hidden container.

Comment: you're right,  it can be messed up by being in a hidden container, i fixed it by rendering the calendar whenever the Tab panel is [shown](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-event-show) rather than [finished rendering](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-event-afterrender).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hiding the container in which the calendar element belongs, then you need to call the calendar's [render()](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render) method when you re-display it, otherwise it can be messed up by being in a hidden container.